# How do I pass Item props via Link to Preview component?

Tags: reactjs

Trying to access and render item props from ListItem to Preview component.

```
const RecipeListItem = (props) => {
  return (
    <Card>
      <Link to={`/recipes/${props.recipe.id}`}>
        <Image src={props.recipe.url} />
      </Link>
      <Card.Content>
        <Card.Header>
          {props.recipe.title}
        </Card.Header>
        <Card.Description>
          {props.recipe.description}
        </Card.Description>
      </Card.Content>
    </Card>
  )
}

export default RecipeListItem;
```

I click on the link,

I get redirected to `http://localhost:3000/recipes/1`

I see Preview component, but can't access the item with Id:1 props to render it on a page.

Here is my Preview component:

```
const RecipePreview = (props) => {
    return (
      <Card>
        <Image src={props.match.params.url} />
        <Card.Content>
          <Card.Header>
            {props.match.params.title}
          </Card.Header>
          <Card.Description>
            {props.match.params.description}
          </Card.Description>
        </Card.Content>
      </Card>
    )
}

export default RecipePreview;
```

Routes:

```
const Main = () => (
  <main>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/recipes' component={RecipeList}/>
      <Route path='/create' component={AddRecipe}/>
      <Route path='/recipes/:recipeId' component={RecipePreview}/>
    </Switch>
  </main>
)

export default Main;
```

My sample data that I'm iterating through looks like this:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
          recipes: {
              "1": {
                id: 1,
                url: 'http://via.placeholder.com/300x300',
                title: '1st Title',
                description: 'some decription 1'
              },
              "2": {
                id: 2,
                url: 'http://via.placeholder.com/300x300',
                title: '1st Title',
                description: 'some decription 1'
              },
              "3": {
                id: 3,
                url: 'http://via.placeholder.com/300x300',
                title: '1st Title',
                description: 'some decription 1'
              }
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the Preview component  please?

Comment: Updated my post with Preview component.. Getting error `'props' is not defined`

Comment: Are you reading the `recipeId` properly?. It will be in `props.params.recipeId`.

Comment: And what does your `match` object contains or is expected to contain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your Preview component is a class, you need to use `this.props.xyz` instead of `props.xyz` to access `xyz` field from props.

Edit:

You need to pass the collection of recipes to the Preview component. The only thing you can get from `props.match.params` is the recipeId that you are passing in.(Read: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match)

You need to search your recipe collection to get the recipe based on the recipeId passed in the param and use it to render the various information.

To pass the recipes collection, your Route needs to change to

```
<Route path='/recipes/:recipeId' render={(props)=><RecipePreview recipes={this.recipes}/>}/>
```

(Read:https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route)

Comment: updated my Preview component again. Now I'm heading somewhere. I see no errors in console but still no luck with rendering item props.

Comment: Can you please post your Routes?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I changed my Route, but how should I change my Preview component to access the props?

Comment: if I do console.log(props); in Preview component I get `{recipes: undefined}`

Comment: Are you passing your recipes collection object in the Route? Or did you jut copy and paste my code? You need to pass your own recipes collection where I have used the `this.recipes` variable in the Route.